# Laplace transform to minus infinity

Tags: laplace-transform

This is a solution to $f(t) = \Theta(t) - 1$ found in my textbook.

$$ Lf(s) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-st}(\Theta(t) - 1) dt = \int^0_{-\infty} e^{-st} (-1) dt = \left[ \frac{e^{-st}}{s} \right]^0_{-\infty} = \frac{1}{s} \left(1 - lim_{a \rightarrow -\infty} e^{-as} \right) = \frac{1}{s} $$

The thing that bothers me is that $\lim_{a -> -\infty} e^{-as} = 0$ in the solution but for me (and wolframalpha) it should be $\infty$.

I've encountered a similair problem at on other exercise, which means I think I've  wrong somewhere. Please explain why the lim-term is 0.

Comment: What is $\Theta$?

Comment: The step function (0 for t < 0 and 1 for t > 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laplace transform is $\frac{1}{s}$, but you forgot the region of convergence for the integral, says $\Re(s) < 0 .$ Actually,

$$\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow -\infty}e^{-st} = 0, \hspace{3mm}\text{for}\hspace{3mm}\Re(s) < 0. $$

Comment: I know it's correct, that wasn't my question. It's the solution that I don't understand. Specially the lim-term which should be infinity.

Comment: But if $\Re(s) < 0$, the limit is not infinity, but zero.

Comment: @iveqy When $Re(s)<0$ you have three minus signs in the real part of the exponent, not two. For example if $s=-1$ then you are taking $\lim_{a \to -\infty} e^a = 0$.

Comment: @Ian, I think you mean $\lim_{a \rightarrow -\infty}e^{-as} = 0$.

Comment: @AlexSilva In general yes; in the specific case $s=-1$ you have $e^{-as}=e^a$. It's an example, chosen to remove variables and thereby hopefully clarify the gist of what's going on. I'll remove it if you think it's not helpful, though.

Comment: It is ok @Ian. I didn't see "$s = -1$".